# Try-catch not working loading XAML resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, try-catch

I have these pieces of code:

```
    private void btnPlanning_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadPage("PlanningView.xaml");
    }

    private void LoadPage(string APage)
    {
        try
        {
            frameMainView.Source = new Uri(APage, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorString = $"Resource <{APage}> not found! ";
            DoLogD(errorString + " " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(errorString);
        }
    }
```

Clicking on *btnPlanning* button, *LoadPage* is called passing a string with the name of the XAML resource I want to load in the frame control *frameMainView*.

If the given resource doesn't not exist, I would like to catch the exception and inform the user.

The problem is that when i click the button (and the resource doesn't exist), I get in any case

> PresentationFramework.pdb not loaded

and a internal *System.IO.IOException* telling me the resource is not available.

Why my try-catch block is not working?

Comment: If you are running in the debugger, you may be breaking on first chance exceptions. Check Debug->Exceptions and make sure only the "User-unhandled" column is checked.

Comment: And if that's not it. Try commenting out your DoLogD() call. Perhaps that is throwing an exception before your message box appears.

Comment: Did you change the target framework recently? 
Please clean and rebuild entire solution after checking the target framework.

Comment: No change of framework.

DoLogD() call doesn't throw exception (but i've removed it in my tests).

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to load the pages into the frame:

1. By setting the source

   frameMainView.Source = new Uri("PlanningView.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
2. By setting the Content:

   frameMainView.Content= new PlanningView();
3. By using the NavigationService:

   frameMainView.NavigationService.Navigate(new PlanningView());

Comment: Options 2) and 3) could workaround my problem. If PlanningView is not present -> compile errors! It could be a solution, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It´s a user interface initialization Problem. Can you get more information from the visual Studio "Output" Window?